# Problems with wilcox.test

Tags: r

I want to apply the `wilcox.test` function to my `dataframe` to compare two groups of size and weight at different sex on fishes. My `dataframe` looks like this

[image: data]):

However, I do not know why I have Error when I use `wilcox.test` in this way:

```
wilcox.test(Pygocentrus.cariba$peso ~ SEXO, mu= 0, alt= "two sided", 
conf.int= T, conf.level= 0.95, pired= FALSE, exact= T, correct= T)
```

which gives the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Pygocentrus.cariba$peso ~ SEXO) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'SEXO')

If someone knows how to fix this problem I will aprreciate it!!

Comment: try with `Pygocentrus.cariba$SEXO`

Comment: Please look into <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve">How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example</a> to get more attention to your question.

Comment: There are multiple spelling errors. Try with this command `wilcox.test(peso ~ SEXO, data = Pygocentrus.cariba, mu= 0, alt= "two.sided", conf.int= T, conf.level= 0.95, paired= FALSE, exact= T, correct= T)`. For a reproducible example run `dput(Pygocentrus.cariba)` and copy the output to your post.